# Parse Data Through JSON And Display it In Expandable List View

Tags: json, android-listview, android-asynctask

Whats the difference between activity and fragment ?

basically i was  given a project to parse  json data and display it in expandable list view as NAME and Class will be list head and other will be child ?

so now i am said to do same using fragments ?
How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the difference

Activity: serves as the presentation layer for our UI

Fragment: within activity represents a behavior or portion of the screen. its like a modular container

to create a project having fragment in an activity, do the following:
In android studio choose blank activity with fragment as shown below:

[image]

Doing this will create a fragment in your activity